# C# Event driving between user controls on win forms

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have a main form (form1) which has a panel (panel1) -- see pic.

[Form1 pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bn4wl.png)

Panel1 loads one of two different user controls based on which button is pressed (to simulate screen changes). I have a button on user control 1 which needs to act (change text) on user control 2.

The issue I have is the user controls are dynamically created with a button press on form 1 (see code below) which is causing me issues trying to link events-

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        panel1.Controls.Add(new Screens.UC1());

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control ctrl in panel1.Controls)
        {
            ctrl.Dispose();
        }
        panel1.Controls.Add(new Screens.UC1());
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control ctrl in panel1.Controls)
        {
            ctrl.Dispose();
        }
        panel1.Controls.Add(new Screens.UC2());
    }
}
```

What is the best way to deal with linking these kinds of items with events when the instance of the objects are dynamically created. I also tried making instances of the screen and then referencing to those, but that ran into scope issues.

Code for UC1 (user control 1)

```
public partial class UC1 : UserControl
{
    public UC1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Event to change text on UC2
    }
}
```

Code for UC2 (user control 2)

```
public partial class UC2 : UserControl
{
    public UC2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void WriteText(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label2.Text = "Text Changed...";
    }
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dispose and create all those controls when the operator presses a button?

Better is to create two UserControls. One with all the Controls you want to show when operator presses button 1 and one with all the Controls you want to show when operator presses button 2.

To create a user control use menu Project - Add User Control, or right click in solution explorer on your project and select `add new item`.

Layout your user controls with all the controls your want to show. Add event handlers etc.

Then in your form:

```
private readonly UserControl userControl!;
private readonly UserControl userControl2;

public MyForm()
{
    InitializeComponent()
    this.userControl1 = new UserControlA(...);
    this.userControl2 = new UserControlB(...);

    // make sure that the user controls are Disposed when this form is Disposed:
    this.Components.Add(this.userControl1);
    this.Components.Add(this.userControl2);
}

void OnButton1Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    // remove userControl2 from the panel
    this.Panel1.Controls.Remove(this.userControl2);
    // add userControl1 to the panel
    this.Panel1.Controls.Add(this.userControl1);        
}
```

This way all the overhead of creating / adding / positioning / add event handlers and all cleanup is only done once: during construction of your form. Switching the user controls will be done in a flash

Comment: Thank you for the response Harald. The program this code represents has about 120 user control "screens" that can be selected from a larger menu. The concern at the time was that two screens cannot be open at the same time. What you proposed has fixed the issue I had... is there a better way to deal with the number of screens available in the actual program?

Comment: I think there are a lot of similarities in your UserControls. Use the designer to put sub-user controls on other user controls. For instance if you have OK / Cancel buttons on bottom right of all 120 user controls, Create a OK/Cancel user control, with the proper handling and put this on all user controls that need these buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but it looks like you are trying to change the state of objects from other objects that cannot have references to the objects they are trying to change.

In this case, I would create a type that functions as some kind of manager that subscribes to events of all of these controls. You can create your own events within a UC class, or just use the Windows Forms `click` event like you are already doing.

Since the handler of the events are defined in the manager, you can easily write logic that will work on the other user controls, as long as the manager has references to them.

Like this:

```
public class ClickTrafficer {
    private UC target;

    public void HandleClick(object sender, UCClickHandlerEventArgs ea) {
        target.WriteText(ea.TextToWrite);
    }
}

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var trafficer = new ClickTrafficer();
    var screen1 = new Screens.UC1();
    screen1.Click += trafficer.HandleClick;
    panel1.Controls.Add(screen1);
}
```

This is a crude idea of what you could do. Missing here are the logic to set whatever the `target` field must be set to. You need to create logic that tells the trafficer which control sets which control's text.

Also, the `ClickTrafficer` I created uses a custom event with custom eventargs, you need to define those or find a way to pass the necessary information through the built in events. Creating events is really easy though so you can look that up online.

Comment: Thank you. You were right on the money with the reference problem.. I will give your suggestion a try.